# CountVectorizer preprocessing related to regex

Tags: python, regex, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, countvectorizer

I am doing text processing using CountVectorizer/logistic regression and comparing f1 score for no preprocessing vs preprocessing. I would like to use regex for preprocessing, so I built a code like below

```
def better_preprocessor(s):
    lower = s.lower()
    lower = re.sub(r'^\w{8,}$', lambda x:x[:7], lower)
    return lower

def a():
    cv = CountVectorizer()
    train = cv.fit_transform(train_data)
    features = cv.get_feature_names()
    cv_dev = CountVectorizer(vocabulary = features)
    dev = cv_dev.fit_transform(dev_data)
    print(features)

    lgr = LogisticRegression(C=0.5, solver="liblinear", multi_class="auto")
    lgr.fit(train, train_labels)
    lgr_pred = lgr.predict(dev)
    score = metrics.f1_score(dev_labels, lgr_pred, average="weighted")
    print('No preprocessing score:', score)

    cv_im = CountVectorizer(preprocessor=better_preprocessor)
    train_im = cv_im.fit_transform(train_data)
    features_im = cv_im.get_feature_names()
    cv_im_dev = CountVectorizer(preprocessor=better_preprocessor, vocabulary = features_im)
    dev_im = cv_im_dev.fit_transform(dev_data)

    lgr.fit(train_im, train_labels)
    lgr_pred_im = lgr.predict(dev_im)
    score_im = metrics.f1_score(dev_labels, lgr_pred_im, average="weighted")
    print('Preprocessing score', score_im)
    print(len(features)-len(features_im))
    print(features_im)

a()
```

I tried to truncate word length larger or equal to 8 into 7, but when I checked vocabulary list using get_feature_names, there was no change. I don't know where I should fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need any regex for this. Use

```
def better_preprocessor(s):
    if len(s) >= 8:
        return s.lower()[:7]
    else:
        return s.lower()
```

The `re.sub(r'^\w{8,}$', lambda x:x[:7], lower)` code takes the `lower` string and tries to match `^\w{8,}$`:

- `^` - start of string
- `\w{8,}`  - eight or more word chars
- `$` - end of string.

The `lambda x:x[:7]` then tries to take the match (where `x` is a match data object) and you try to slice the match data object. Probably you meant to use `x.group()[:7]`, but it is still an overkill here.

If you plan to extract all words from a string and truncate them, you need to specify what a word is for you and use

```
def better_preprocessor(s):
    return re.sub(r'\b(\w{7})\w+', r'\1', s.lower())
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dglhx8/1)

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(\w{7})` - Group 1 (referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern): seven word chars
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars

Comment: Really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: One quick question. I tried to remove front and end underscore from strings, so I used ```re.sub(r'(^_+|_+$)', '', s)``` . It worked with regex check, but when I run it in the function, it didn't remove the underscore from vocabulary. Am I missing something?

Comment: @aquantum Strings or words? `re.sub(r'\b_+|_+\b', '', s)` will work for words. If you can provide examples, I will help more.

Comment: Thanks this worked! Could you let me know why mine didn't work compared to yours?

Comment: @aquantum `^` matches start of string and `$` matches end of string only.

Comment: Yes I tried to do that but this didn't remove underscore from the beginning. (e.g. __book --> remain same)

Comment: same as this one. I tried to remove last "ed" from the words so I tried ```re.sub(r'\b(\w+)ed$\b', r'\1', s)``` and worked in the simulator, but didn't work in the function above. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: @aquantum Remove `$`, use `re.sub(r'\b(\w+)ed\b', r'\1', s)`

Comment: Could you let me know why mine doesn't work? It looks like both should work... sorry keep asking

Comment: @aquantum Just read what I say: **`^` matches start of string and `$` matches end of string only.**

Comment: Yep. I saw your comment. The confusion point is that when I would like to remove last 'ed' from the string, that would be the end of string, so I thought I could use $ sign at the end. Is there any logic I'm missing?

Comment: @aquantum No, just your text may have invisible chars at the end.

Comment: Ah, now I got it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of doing it using `analyzer` parameter:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

def better_preprocessor(s):
    lower = s.lower().split()
    lower = [x[:7] for x in lower]
    for l in lower:
        yield l

lower = ["hello how are you doing today crocodilesaway","hello how are you"]

cv = CountVectorizer(analyzer=better_preprocessor, )
cv.fit_transform(lower)
cv.get_feature_names()

['are', 'crocodi', 'doing', 'hello', 'how', 'today', 'you']
```